# drupal site url redirecting to server config page

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

have created a basic page and made a tpl file for it. (node--{nid}.tpl.php) and have given a clean url to the page.

but when the page is called (e.g. drupal/aboutus) . it redirects to the wamp server page showing the server info..

below is a screenshot of what is returned.
[image: screenshot]

kindly assist what can be the possible cause and any solution.

(and do not understand why this question is not passing SO quality standards)

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue solved by enabling re write engine in apache 
[enable rewrite engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)..

thank you for the time though